# $f $ is analytic, and maps the unit disk to itself; $f(0)=0$. Prove $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for $z\in D$; $|f'(0)|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having difficulties with the following problem:

> $\bf Given$: $   f$ is an analytic map from unit disk $D$ to itself and: $f(0)=0$. $\bf To \; prove:$   $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for $z\in D$; and: $|f'(0)|\leq 1$

What I thought is:
$$|f(z)|\leq 1,$$ because $f$ maps to unit disk.

This is apparently wrong.
But how then should I approach this problem?

Comment: The expression $f(z) \leq |z|$ is not meaningful: $\leq$ is not defined for complex numbers. Do you mean $|f(z)|$?

Comment: @Svinepels Thank you, yes indeed. I changed it.

Comment: Why do you need to prove $f(0)=0$?  You are given that.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry; I've changed it to the actual problem now,

Comment: This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: @user110822 I see. What I don't understand is: why do they choose $f'(0)=0$? (sure there is a singularity for $z=0$, but why should we make it analytic this way? ).

Comment: @user104662 $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=f'(0)$

Comment: @user110822 why do they actually choose $g$ to be: $g:=f/z$ ?

Comment: @user104662 Because $|g(z)| \leq 1 $ implies lemma. See proof.

Comment: @user104662 And they choose $g(0)=f'(0)$, and not $f'(0)=0$. You "only" prove that $|f'(0)|\leq 1$, but you don't now that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @user110822 Yes I begin to understand now what you meant. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $g(z) = f(z)/z$.

Comment: Thanks, that hint is also given in the question :). But I don't know why exactly.. Can you tell me why you propose this?